# call: argument [object Object] is not a function

Tags: react-admin

I am using React-admin and i am trying to test with the "jsonplaceholder.typicode"
When i compile this code

```
 import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from "react-admin";
import { UserList } from "./users";
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

I have this error "call: argument [object Object] is not a function"

what is my mistake?...
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Use code from documentation https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-json-server

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

import { UserList } from './users';

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```